Python Pandas how to prevent text wrapping within dataframe
How do I prevent a pandas dataframe from wrapping text for columns with longer strings? I have the below dataframe where all of the column names have line breaks and certain columns, like ETF Category, wrap the text because the string is too long for the column. How do I make the width of the longest string (weather the column header or a column value) so that all rows are flat? This is similar to the 'Wrap Text' operation in excel.
enter image description here
Want it to look flat like this, but with all columns included:
enter image description here
How do I prevent a pandas dataframe from wrapping text for columns with longer strings?
